# C# WPF Background style for all Windows in ResourceDictionary - Target type with relative path?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm organizing my projects with folders. So I have put all window files inside "MyWindows" folder, and in another folder called "Styles" I have a ResourceDictionary. Now I want to write a style for background that would apply to all desired windows, like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="Ozadje">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF66A7B6" Offset="0.997"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFAEF1F1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFACEAEA"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF9BF1E6"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBFD1CF" Offset="0.06"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6CAAB7" Offset="0.924"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF99BFC4"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="MyWindows/Window1" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}" />
```

I can't set this because all Windows are not in a `local:` namespace that resource dictionary is. And another problem is that styles for windows must be applied manually for each Window via reference.

Is there anything I can do - besides calling **Style="{StaticResource Ozadje}"** in Window properties?...I'm curious if I can use a relative path.

P.S.: I'm a beginner in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a namespace mapping for the namespace in which `Window1` is defined, e.g.:

```
<Style xmlns:MyWindows="clr-namespace:MyWindows"
       TargetType="{x:Type MyWindows:Window1}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Ozadje}" />
```

Comment: great, I couldn't find that answer anywhere. However, bad side effect Is that style Isn't seen in design mode. Thanks a lot !